# jQuery Ajax timeout kicks in on Windows browser but not Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

So I've this piece of code which checks for internet speed and returns back some result. In order to deal with non-connectivity or disconnect issues while the speed check is going on, I put a `timeout` wait of 10 seconds.

This timeout works fine on a desktop browser (I started the test, pulled the plug, and after 10 seconds the `error` function kicked in.

But while trying to run the same page on Android browser, the `error` function does not respond even after 30-40 seconds or so.

This makes me believe this has got something to do with Android settings and was hoping any one having knowledge in that area would point me in the right direction. Here is the code btw:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'internet-speed.php',
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function(x, t, m){
            if(t==="timeout") 
            {
                    $('span#wait').html('Timed out');
            }
            else
            {
                $('span#wait').html('Something went wrong');
            }
        },          
        success:function(data)
        {
                  $('span#wait').html('Your speed is '+data+'kbps'); 
        }
});
```

Comment: Are you using any other add-ins/helpers/frameworks along with jQuery?

Comment: Can you try `bind`-ing the function that calls $.ajax() ?

Comment: I could, but the code works fine on Android too if it remains connected to the net, i.e it goes to the `success` function after about 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Okay, can you try your `$.ajax` with these two options  `tryCount:0,retryLimit:3` ?